# Overpass-api comparison operators

Tags: comparison-operators, overpass-api

In the post  ["Date ranges with Overpass API"](http://gis.19327.n8.nabble.com/Date-ranges-with-Overpass-API-td5886864.html) Roland Olbricht announced public beta for the next Overpass API release. I try to use the comparison operators "==", "<", "<=", ">", and ">=" to find nodes with tag population which is greater then or smaller then any number

```
node[population]
(if:"population">5834)({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

unfortunately comparison operators seems not to work at all. I try function number()
    `node[population]
    (if:number("population")>5834)({{bbox}});
    (._;>;);
    out;`

One thing that works is code like this

```
node[population]
(if:!is_number("population"))({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

therefore I have a question whether anyone had contact with the beta and these operators?

Answer (score 4):

The updated documentation has been published on the OSM Wiki in the meantime: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL

For your use case, you need to use the following syntax to:

- Find all nodes with `population` tag in the current bbox
- That have a population numeric tag
- Where the actual value of the `population` tag is larger than 5834:

Query:

```
node[population] 
    (if: is_number(t[population]) && number(t[population])>5834 )
    ({{bbox}});
out;
```

Due to automatic type conversions you should also be able to use the following shorter variant:

```
node[population] (if: t[population] > 5834)({{bbox}});
out;
```